# How to organize and upload huge volume of images into Flickr account

Tags: images, flickr

I have organized my personal photographs in my pc and maintain several copies of backup. The images are in folder with naming convention of [YYYY-MM-DD Event or Place Name]. I want to upload my images into a Flickr account. My questions are:

1. How do I organize the images, so that they can be arranged, sorted and
   searched by date, event or place name. (I didn't find concept of
   folders/directories in Flickr.)
2. Uploading images 65 GB of image manually would take a hell lot of effort. Is there a way to upload
   the images automatically? (of course, mean while I must also
   maintain the dates, place, event names)

Thank you

Comment: I hope you have a quality internet connection. 65gb @ 1mb/s ~= 18 hours...

Answer (score 2):

Easily done with a script like the following. It pretty much does what you want but you will need to make  modifications to the source to handle your particular naming convention.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flickrsmartsync

Your events or places will become sets or tags. Then you will able to search them easily.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But seriously, do I have to know programming in Python? To upload my images?

Comment: If you really want a fully automated way to upload 1000s of images, then yes you need something like this. If programming is not your thing, try contacting the author of the script to help you out. The changes should be easy and quick for him...

Answer (score 1):

This is a great option:

1. [**JUploader**](http://juploadr.sourceforge.net/) - Cross-platform, java-based uploading tool to get photos off of your hard drive and up to Flickr easily. Works like a charm, but looks dated and doesn't look pretty. Who cares - it works!

Alternatively, you may use the [**Flickr D&D Uploader**](https://www.flickr.com/photos/upload/). I've noticed it to be rather slow, plus depending on browser - it might not work terribly well...

One more thing, **Preloadr** *(Yahoo! Search)* will image process plus optimize photos before it uploads. I've not used this tool, but I've read it works great.